# Deprecated feature 'INSERT NULL into TIMESTAMP columns' is not supported in this version of SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a web API that uses Entity Framework Code First. Patient domain entity looks like:

```
public class Patient
{
    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    ...
    public byte[] Version { get; private set; }                
}
```

Patient table is like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Patient]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [FirstName] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ...
    [Version] ROWVERSION NOT NULL,      
)
```

If I run this locally, patient entries are succesfully added to the database, so it works fine (SQL Server 2008 R2).

However, if I deploy to Azure and run it there, I get the exception:

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. Deprecated feature 'INSERT NULL into TIMESTAMP columns' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

If I remove the Version column from the table; and the Version property from the domain entity, it works also on Azure. If I remove it from the domain entity only (and leave it in the table), is also works!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Interesting behavior on Azure. It works for me in the local sql server 2012 Express edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Code First needs to know that the Version column is the concurrency token. If I add:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>().ToTable("Patient").Property(p => p.Version).IsRowVersion().IsConcurrencyToken();
```

...it works.

Answer (score 3):

Decorate your code first version property with the timestamp attribute and all will be well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583#TimeStamp

Comment: Thanks! It's probably going to work, but I like to keep my entities clean... I used another approach (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you got some nullable TIMESTAMP columns at your schema.
It ill work at your local SQL Server 2008 but ill fail for SQL 2012 and is likely Azure ill run the newest SQL Version by default.

See this reference:
[Deprecated features in SQL 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx)

You can try to set the compatibility level
[Setting compatibility level for SQL 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb510680.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use TIMESTAMP anyware. I use ROWVERSION.

Comment: The Azure database has already compatibility level 100 it seems, which is Sql Server 2008.

Comment: That's awkward. It's a long shot but can you try setting that column to DEFAULT NULL or DEFAULT GETDATE()?

Comment: Thanks, it sais: "Defaults cannot be created on columns of data type timestamp."

Comment: That means you can change that rowversion to DATETIME. Really awkward but at least a datetime with a default is supposed to work

Comment: Struck by curiosity about this issue I'm reading the documentations. It appears you can declare rowversion and timestamp but you cannot declare timestamp column with a name. Also you cannot set a value at update/insert (works likely with IDENTITY) and maybe that's the problem. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Well, the Version property is actually never used, so I don't set it to a value or something...

Comment: If I remove the Version property from my domain entity but leave it in the database, it works again. So if I create a new domain entity, and Version defaulting to null, it doesn't work.

Comment: Allright, it works by letting code first know that Version is the row version property (see my answer).